# Navigation Bar - Transparent Issue

Tags: css, html

[image]

I don't understand why I am able to see through my navigation bar like this. I can even highlight the text through it. Any help guys?

Here's the HTML and CSS, when I test this on an online editor, it works properly. But on my local code, it doesn't.

```css
    nav{
    position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    }
      nav ul{
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 100px;
        display: inline-table;
      }
        nav ul li{
          float: left;
          -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        }

    nav ul li:hover{background: rgba(0,0,0,.15);}
    nav ul li:hover > ul{display: block;}
    nav ul li{
      float: left;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
      nav ul li a{
        display: block; 
        padding: 30px 20px;
        color: #222; 
        font-size: .9em;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation"> 

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Where are your `styles` for your `Lorem Ipsum`?

Comment: Can you post the complete section of your html including the Lorem Ipsum section

Comment: Here's the link to the HTML and CSS of the lorem ipsum section: https://imgur.com/a/ZYWFa3V

Stack Overflow won't allow me to put more code into my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant comment, so this appears as an answer but its more a suggestion as I cant see all your code (like where is the Lorem Ipsum coming from?)

You've set the **nav** to **position:fixed**, this removes itself from the structure of the DOM. I dont see a z-index property there so that might fix the situation. The text will be hidden behind the navigation if you set the z-index to anything greater than 0.

```
nav {
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
...
}
```

To make sure the text sits underneath the navigation, you may want to set a margin-top to your body tag equating to the height of the navigation bar.

Comment: I would recommend not using z-index for something as simple as this, as z-indexing can cause problems later on and is actually quite unintuitive to most people (I would be willing to bet money that it doesn't work the way you think it does). I would instead recommend fixing the way that position:fixed and position:absolute are interacting to cause the overlap.